# Empty Test Plan see log File errors

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to open the Jmeter script and getting " Empty Test Plan see log File errors" below is the Error description can some one please look into and see what is the cause of this error.

: org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.xmlformatter.XMLFormatPostProcessor
line number         : 75

### version             : 2.11 r1554548

2014/09/29 15:11:53 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error org.apache.jmeter.exceptions.IllegalUserActionException: Empty TestPlan - see log file
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:174)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:136)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:92)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your JMeter Script(JMX) which is an XML might have some syntax errors or might be corrupted.

Open up the script in NotePad++ and try to see if there are any errors in line 75.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had this problem after upgrading to Java 8. Downloading JMeter 2.12 seems to have fixed the problem.